# Write any positive integer as a sum of squares

Tags: number-theory

With `n = 17` I would like to get

> {4, 1}

and with `n = 999`

> {31, 6, 1, 1}

so that, for example,

```
Total[#^2 & /@ {31, 6, 1, 1}]
```

gives

> 999

I don't want to get all possibilities, but only the shortest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Module[{n = 1, results}, 
   While[(results = Sqrt[IntegerPartitions[#, {n}, Range@Floor@Sqrt[#]^2]]) == {}, 
    n++]; results] &[999]

(*
{{31, 6, 1, 1}, {31, 5, 3, 2}, {30, 9, 3, 3}, {30, 7, 7, 1}, {30, 7, 
  5, 5}, {29, 11, 6, 1}, {29, 10, 7, 3}, {27, 15, 6, 3}, {27, 14, 7, 
  5}, {27, 13, 10, 1}, {27, 11, 10, 7}, {26, 17, 5, 3}, {26, 15, 7, 
  7}, {26, 11, 11, 9}, {25, 19, 3, 2}, {25, 18, 7, 1}, {25, 18, 5, 
  5}, {25, 17, 9, 2}, {25, 17, 7, 6}, {25, 15, 10, 7}, {25, 14, 13, 
  3}, {25, 13, 13, 6}, {23, 21, 5, 2}, {23, 19, 10, 3}, {23, 18, 11, 
  5}, {23, 17, 10, 9}, {23, 15, 14, 7}, {22, 21, 7, 5}, {22, 17, 15, 
  1}, {22, 15, 13, 11}, {21, 21, 9, 6}, {21, 19, 14, 1}, {21, 18, 15, 
  3}, {21, 17, 13, 10}, {19, 19, 14, 9}, {19, 18, 17, 5}, {18, 15, 15,
   15}, {17, 17, 15, 14}}
*)

Total /@ (%^2)

(*
{999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999,
999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999,
999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999}
*)
```

Assuming you want the "smallest" termed of the "shortest", (and re-stealing from *Sektor*)...

```
With[{num = #}, 
   Catch[If[(result = PowersRepresentations[num, #, 2]) !=  {}, 
       Throw[Reverse@First@result]] & /@ Range@4]] &[999]
```

If the order (e.g., your OP has terms descending) does not matter, you can remove the `Reverse@`.

Comment: very nice, but I only want `{31, 6, 1, 1}` avoiding, if possible, all the other calculations (For me `{31, 6, 1, 1}` is the most "natural" form).

Comment: @eldo: You said "shortest". These are *all* the "shortest". If you want something else, clarify your question as to what *your* definition of "shortest" is. If it's the "smallest" total factors, just prepend `First@` to either answer...

Comment: Extremely fast, plus I like the missing `While`. My only remaining question: Why `Range@4` and not 3 or 5 ?

Comment: See e.g., *Lagrange's four-square theorem*...

Comment: already proved in 1770. I should go back in time or to school or delete the question.

Comment: @eldo: That made me LOL - I can't tell you how many times I agonized over a proof, only to later find someone from the stone age already did it, and better...

Answer (score 6):

Shamelessly stealing, but using a built-in function

```
Block[{n = 1, results}, 
       While[(results = PowersRepresentations[#, n, 2]) == {}, n++]; 
       results] &[999]
```

Comment: +1 - I'd completely forgotten that function.

Comment: :D You were a little faster, so I had to find another way to keep my edge

Answer (score 3):

```
f = Module[{n = 1, res}, While[(res = Reduce`SumOfSquaresReps[n, #]) == {}, n++]; res]&;

f[17]
(* {{1, 4}} *)

f[999][[1]]
(* {1, 1, 6, 31}  *)

f[999]
(* {{1, 1, 6, 31}, {1, 6, 11, 29}, {1, 7, 7, 30}, {1, 7, 18, 25},
    {1, 10,13, 27}, {1, 14, 19, 21}, {1, 15, 17, 22}, {2, 3, 5, 31},
    {2, 3, 19, 25}, {2, 5, 21, 23}, {2, 9, 17, 25}, {3, 3, 9, 30}, 
    {3, 5, 17, 26}, {3, 6, 15, 27}, {3, 7, 10, 29}, {3, 10, 19, 23},
    {3, 13, 14, 25}, {3, 15, 18, 21}, {5, 5, 7, 30}, {5, 5, 18, 25}, 
    {5, 7, 14, 27}, {5, 7, 21, 22}, {5, 11, 18, 23}, {5, 17, 18, 19}, 
    {6, 7, 17, 25}, {6, 9, 21, 21}, {6, 13, 13, 25}, {7, 7, 15, 26}, 
    {7, 10, 11, 27}, {7, 10, 15, 25}, {7, 14, 15, 23}, {9, 10, 17, 23}, 
    {9, 11, 11, 26}, {9, 14, 19, 19}, {10, 13, 17, 21}, {11, 13, 15, 22}, 
    {14, 15, 17, 17}, {15, 15, 15, 18}} *)
```

Comment: I suppose this is one of those (in)famous undocumented functions? When omitting the `While ... n++` it becomes terribly slow. Excellent answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

```
squarePartition[n_] := squarePartition[n, 1, Table[k^2, {k, 1, Floor[Sqrt[n]]}]];
squarePartition[n_, l_, squares_] := 
  Module[{result = IntegerPartitions[n, {l}, squares]},
   Sqrt[First[result]] /; result =!= {}
   ];
squarePartition[n_, l_, squares_] := squarePartition[n, l + 1, squares];

squarePartition /@ {17, 999}
(* {{4, 1}, {31, 6, 1, 1}} *)
```

Comment: This gives (I think - depends on OP definition of "shortest') incorrect answer. E.g., for 10000000 it returns `{3162, 41, 8, 3, 1, 1}`, where in fact there are four representations using only two squares...

Comment: @rasher I haven't checked that and assumed it does the right thing. Now I have to iterate as you do through all different lengths :-( I tried to do it in pure functional style..

Answer (score 1):

```
k = 1;
m[1] = 999;
While[m[k] =!= 0, n[k] = Floor@Sqrt[m[k]]; k = k + 1;
 m[k] = m[k - 1] - (Floor@Sqrt[m[k - 1]])^2];
sol = n[#] & /@ Range[1, k - 1]

(* {31, 6, 1, 1}  *)
```