# Undocumented function SumOfSquaresReps

Tags: number-theory, undocumented

There is an interesting (and documented) number-theoretic function in MMA called [PowersRepresentations[$n$, $k$, $p$]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowersRepresentations.html).

It gives the distinct representations of the integer $n$ as a sum of $k$ non-negative $p$-th integer powers.

---

I recently heard about related undocumented function `SumOfSquaresReps`.

How can I find out more on that undocumented function (number of arguments etc.)? What does it do exactly? How does it relate to `PowersRepresentations`, esp. performance-wise? Is there `SumOfCubesReps`, etc.?

The only place on the Internet known to me where this function is mentioned and used is [@kglr answer to a question on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51301/write-any-positive-integer-as-a-sum-of-squares/51303#51303).

---

Related:

[How does Mathematica compute how to write integers as the sum of k non-negative pth integer powers so quickly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132751/how-does-mathematica-compute-how-to-write-integers-as-the-sum-of-k-non-negative)

Comment: "number of arguments etc." - as you can surmise from kglr's answer, it takes two arguments: ``Reduce`SumOfSquaresReps[k, n]`` returns all possible lists of `k` positive integers whose squares sum to `n`.

Comment: The function is implemented in top-level code, so if you are interested you can look at its implementation using `Spelunk[Reduce\`SumOfSquaresReps]` (you need "spelunking tools" for this, see [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/27951) to get them).

Comment: Vivid, could you explain what you would like to see in an answer? As I mentioned the first time you asked the question, you can access the actual implementation code for `SumOfSquaresReps`: ``ClearAttributes[Reduce`SumOfSquaresReps, ReadProtected];??Reduce`SumOfSquaresReps``. What would be more credible and official than the code itself?

Comment: @MarkoB I would like to see everything that I mentioned in the question: implementation details (if possible), perf comparison SumOfSquaresReps vs PowersRepresentations, details on other related undocumented and documented functions, etc... An overview of general methods for exploring internals of built-in functions would definitely not hurt. Thanks for interest and info so far!