# How does Mathematica compute how to write integers as the sum of k non-negative pth integer powers so quickly?

Tags: number-theory

"`PowersRepresentations[n,k,p]` gives the distinct representations of the integer `n` as a sum of `k` non-negative `p`-th integer powers"

**Documentation: [PowersRepresentations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowersRepresentations.html)**

How does *Mathematica* do this computation so quickly? Is there a fast algorithm? What is it?

I am particularly interested in the case where $n$ is the sum of $k$ squares of positive integers.

Comment: There is a little man inside the computer who is good at sums

Answer (score 10):

You can view the code for `PowersRepresentations` using

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; 
PrintDefinitions @PowersRepresentations
```

Comment: Can one view codes this way for any function?

Comment: @Mirko, unfortunately, 'PrintDefinitions' does not give the code for Kernel functions; it just returns '<Kernel Function>'.

Comment: @kglr That's because closed-source software hates its users :)

Comment: @kglr You will find any function is *kernel function* when you arive v11.2. Even [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOqXr.png) :)

Comment: @yode, interesting.